# Types of Edges In a Triangulated Mesh

Tags: python, bmesh

I added the triangulate modifier on a mesh and then applied it. For this mesh in edit mode, I see two types of edges, thick bright ones from the original mesh and thin black ones, newly created by the modifier.

[image: triangulated mesh with two types of edges]

Now if I create a new bmesh having new faces with the same vertex coordinates of the triangulated mesh, all the edges in the new mesh are uniform color.

[image]

The new mesh also has slightly different shape. Is there any explanation for the two types of edges in the original mesh and is it possible to replicate them in a new mesh, so that I get exactly the same shape?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is: `smooth` attribute value of the edges with orange border is `False`, that of the ones with black is `True`. I guess, the new edges added by Triangulate modifier are `smooth`. So when recreating a mesh vertex by vertex, one needs to copy the `edge.smooth` attribute along with the vertex coordinates.